# Show that $|A|=|B|$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $\mathbb F$ be a field, let $n$ be a positive integer, and let A=$(a_{ij})\in M_{n\times n}(\mathbb F)$. Let B=$(b_{ij})\in M_{n\times n}(\mathbb F)$ defined by
$$ b_{ij} = \begin{cases} a_{ij}+a_{i,j+1} & \textit{if j < n,}\\
a_{in} & \textit{otherwise.}
\end{cases}$$
Show that $|A|=|B|$,

I tried thinking of it as the summations indexed by permutations but I didn't make it far with that. How would you prove this?

Answer (score 0):

The matrix $B$ can be obtained from $A$ by elementary row operations; if you already know that elementary row operations preserve determinants, then this applies here. If not, note that $B=AJ$, where
$$J = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 0 \\ 1 & 1 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 1 & \cdots & 0 & 0 \\ \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots & \vdots \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 1 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$$
Since $J$ is lower-diagonal, its determinant is the product of its diagonal entries (i.e. $|J|=1$), so the result follows using multiplicity of determinants.